# Why does an AWS ALB configured for a AspNetCore Lambda function give a 502 after when redirected?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-mvc, aws-alb

I have project setup based on the AspNetCoreWebApp template from [aws-lambda-dotnet](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/tree/4a6eb6d/Blueprints/BlueprintDefinitions/Msbuild-NETCore_2_1/AspNetCoreWebApp/template/src/BlueprintBaseName.1).

The lambda entry point is setup the same as the [template](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/1602d8355ab603c49ea8e7b48a8da29654c0e4ac/Blueprints/BlueprintDefinitions/Msbuild-NETCore_2_1/AspNetCoreWebApp/template/src/BlueprintBaseName.1/LambdaEntryPoint.cs#L17).

I can see an unsecured page fine, but when attempting to go to a secured page, I get a `502` Status Code response from the load balancer.

Based on [aws troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-502-issues):

> The target response is malformed or contains HTTP headers that are not valid.

The lambda function redirects work fine fine with API Gateway in front of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to read the [Readme](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/blob/4a6eb6d571b7067d1237684dc17f2fda4320978c/Blueprints/BlueprintDefinitions/Msbuild-NETCore_2_1/AspNetCoreWebApp/template/src/BlueprintBaseName.1/Readme.md):

> Change the base class to Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.ApplicationLoadBalancerFunction when using an Application Load Balancer.

Although the Lambda function seems to work using the `APIGatewayProxyFunction` base class, the headers for `Content-Type` will come back as `[null]` during a redirect which the ALB does not appear to support. Change the base class of `LambdaEntryPoint` to `ApplicationLoadBalancerFunction` and the redirects will work correctly.